# Which JOIN to use

Tags: php, sql, join

I'm trying to get info from a table.

I have boards and sub-boards. The column `sub_id` in table `board` tells me whether or not the board is a sub-board or not. If it is a sub-board then the `id` of the parent board is the value, if it isn't then the cell is null.

I wrote this to display whether or not a board has any sub-boards:

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM board WHERE sub_id='$boardId'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print "<br>Sub-collections:<br>";
Print "<font size='5pt'><a href='/board/index/".$info['id']."'>".$info['board_name']."    </a></font>";
} 
?>
```

This works fine.

Now I want to write a similar code to name the parent board (if the board is a sub) but this is where I'm having trouble.

I came up with:

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("select * from board WHERE id='$boardId' AND sub_id IS NOT NULL")     or die(mysql_error());
$issub = mysql_fetch_array($data);
?>
```

then using...

```
<?php if(($issub)): ?>
<?php echo $issub['sub_id'] ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

To display.

The problem is without a `join` I cannot show anything other than the `id` of the parent board. I don't know which columns to join in order to extract info like `board_name` etc.

EDIT:

popovitsj's suggestion:

```
<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM board b WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM board WHERE b.id     = sub_id)") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print "<br>Sub-collection of:<br>";
Print "<font size='5pt'><a href='/board/index/".$info['id']."'>".$info['board_name']."    </a></font>";
} 
?>
```

This works to a certain extent. It correctly displays the parent board on the subboard page, but also displays it erroneously on the parent board page.

EDIT2:

After researching LEFT JOIN at Meier's suggestion I eventually got it to work using this code:

`SELECT * FROM board a LEFT JOIN board b ON a.sub_id = b.id WHERE a.sub_id LIKE b.id AND a.id='$boardId'`

Comment: Little bit confusing that you call the column that refers to the parent sub_board. You should've called it parent_board.

Comment: Having a hard time to understand what your tables looks like. Can you please make it clearer?

Comment: It isn't. It's `sub_id`. I wanted to be able to do it in as few columns as possible.

Comment: there is one table = `board`. Within it is information about boards a user creates: `id`, `board_name`, `user_id`, `description`, `time_created`. I added a new column: `sub_id`. This enables users to designate a board to another. If they choose to, for example, link boards with id's `56` and `102` together as 102 the subboard of 56. In the column `sub_id` of board 102, the value will be `56`. This tells me that board 102 is a subboard of board 56. Nothing is altered for board 56's data. I just use sql to check if its `id` is being used as a `sub_id`.

Comment: Yes, and this is confusing. Think about it, what does sub_id refer to? Does it refer to the sub_board? No, it refers to the parent of the sub_board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer the question: are you 100% sure that the `$boardid` does not come directly from  http and is therefore manipulable by the user, so your users can not start a sql injection?

The join you need is a "outer self join". Outer join because you also want to display boards that do not have a parent. Outer join is also named left join. 
A self join because the table is joined to itself. The trick with the self join is to give  the table different names in the statement, so you can distinguish between th parent and the child.

A quick google search for "sql outer self join" gave me this, which explains it quite nicely.
The example is with employees and managers, and the managers are also employees. So the example is quite similar to yours:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/08/sql-server-the-self-join-inner-join-and-outer-join/

Comment: Tried this without luck:
select * from board a left join board b on a.id = b.sub_id WHERE b.sub_id LIKE $boardId
Any suggestions, its still calling the sub-boards, not parents. What do I tweek?

Comment: I fiddled with it and got it to work:
SELECT * FROM board a LEFT JOIN board b ON a.sub_id = b.id WHERE a.sub_id LIKE b.id AND a.id='$boardId'

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions to this. One possible one is:

```
SELECT * FROM Board b
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM Board
    WHERE b.id = sub_id);
```

Another possible solution could be this, this only shows 'root' parent boards. (boards with no parents themselves).

```
SELECT * FROM Board b
WHERE sub_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This works to a certain extent:

    <?php 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM board b WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *     FROM board WHERE b.id = sub_id)") or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { 
    Print "<br>Sub-collection of:<br>";
    Print "<font size='5pt'><a     href='/board/index/".$info['id']."'>".$info['board_name']."</a>    </font>";
    } 
    ?>

On the subboard page it correctly identifies the parent board. But on the parent board page it also says "Sub-collection of..." and lists itself.

Comment: This query just gets all parents. If you want all subs of a certain parent, use a different query.